# Passe data beetwen view controller in UITableView

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, uitableview, parse-platform

I try to pass an `PFObject` with the current `ViewController` to another `ViewController` when the user select a cell from the `UITableView`, this is my code :

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
static NSString *identifier = @"boxCell";
NSInteger row = [indexPath row];
boxTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];
if(cell == nil){
    cell = [[boxTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:identifier];
}

PFObject *boxe = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"Boxe"];
boxe = [self.arrayBox objectAtIndex:row];


PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Boxe"];
[query whereKey:@"objectId" equalTo:boxe.objectId];

[query getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFObject *object, NSError *error) {
    if(object){
        // I instanciate the PFObject
        box = object;
        cell.nomBoxe.text = object[@"contenu"];
        cell.qteBoxe.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ boxes disponbiles",object[@"quantite"]];
        cell.prixBoxe.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@€",object[@"prix"]];
        cell.descriptionBoxe.text = object[@"description"];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Erreur lors de chargement, erreur : %@",error.description);
    }
}];
return cell;
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segueToBoxDetail" sender:self];
}


-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"segueToBoxDetail"]) {
    boxDetailViewController *boxDetailVC = [segue destinationViewController];
    boxDetailVC.box = box;
    }
}
```

I declare the PFObject :

```
@implementation RestauCardViewController{
PFObject *box;
}
```

In the other ViewController, I have a property for the object box :

```
@property(nonatomic) PFObject *box;
```

I got this error :

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIViewController setBox:]:
>   unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x12aad9100'

Any help please

Comment: what is the error you are getting...

Comment: I got this error : Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIViewController setBox:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x12aad9100'

Comment: not sure but probably your box property is not allocated or initialized

Comment: can you show code from `boxDetailViewController`

Comment: @VivekMolkar
#import "boxDetailViewController.h"
@ interface boxDetailViewController ()
@ property(nonatomic) PFObject *box;

@ end

Comment: Can you quickly verify my answer if it runs fine

Comment: are you sure that your segue and function names are correct?

maybe in storyboard there is some old segue still attached that points into nowhere?

Comment: I think my segue are correct, because when i delete this line, that work but the PFObject in the other view controller does not instanciate :         boxDetailVC.box = box;

Comment: hey can you move the `property(nonatomic) PFObject *box; ` to .h file.

Comment: @VivekMolkar Yes but he doesn't work

Comment: Is it still the same error?

Comment: @VivekMolkar Yes I get the same error

Comment: A last try hope this solves. In your storyboard check if the destination view controllers class. if it is not `boxDetailViewController` the assign it.

Comment: @VivekMolkar I checked but he dosen't work

Comment: your destination view controller class is of type `boxDetailViewController`?

Comment: Excatly the destination view controller class is of type boxDetailViewController

Answer (score 0):

In your `prepareForSegue:` replace your declaration with this line.

```
boxDetailViewController *boxDetailVC = (boxDetailViewController*)[segue destinationViewController];
```

**EDIT**
Plz move

```
property(nonatomic) PFObject *box;
```

line to your .h file

Comment: It does not work, but when I delete this line does it work :         boxDetailVC.box = box;

Comment: It will certainly work because that is the line that throws error. The error you posted means there is no such property in the case `box`.

Comment: What happen if you put boxDetailVC.box= nil ? Crashed ?

Answer (score 0):

You are writing property in the wrong place. Currently you are writing it in the class extension. Class extension is used to keep the data secret to that class only.

Try to write the same property in .h file.

property declared in .h file are accessible to other classes. So other class can access its accessor methods and set its value.

Please let me know.

Comment: I declared the property in .h file but it doesn't work

Comment: ohhh... Would you please check if there is any selector named "setBox" is there in your storyboard. But it is not there in your code. Please check

Comment: I checked but there is  any selector named "setBox"

Answer (score 0):

I too got the same error. Solved it so thought to share here too.

I am having a `UIViewController` class which is connected with segue to `UITableViewController`.

Actually i was connecting the segue with the `UINavigationController`.

Changing the segue connection to `UITableViewController` solved the problem.